# How to center a JavaFX Group correctly and set the (inverse) pivot using translations in 3D Space?

Tags: 3d, javafx-2, pivot, translation, transform

**Description:**

I´m referring to the tutorial from Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/transformations/jfxpub-transformations.htm using the source code from transformations.zip, which is offered as a download on this page. I don´t understand, why they center the xylophone in 3D-Space like that and why they are calculating the (inverse) pivot using translations.

So they are creating a lot of groups, containing rectangles, representing the xylophone, which are finally added to a group called `cam`.

```
class Cam extends Group {
Translate t  = new Translate();
Translate p  = new Translate();
Translate ip = new Translate();
Rotate rx = new Rotate();
{ rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); }
Rotate ry = new Rotate();
{ ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS); }
Rotate rz = new Rotate();
{ rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS); }
Scale s = new Scale();
public Cam() { super(); getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rx, rz, ry, s, ip); }
}

final Cam camOffset = new Cam();
final Cam cam = new Cam();
...
camOffset.getChildren().add(cam);
...

final Scene scene = new Scene(camOffset, 800, 600, true);
...
```

The Group `cam` is added to another group called `camOffset`, which is added to the `scene` as its root node.

**Until then** everything is understandable for me, but there is a method, called `frameCam(..)` which is calling 4 other methods, used for positioning and scale:

```
public void setCamOffset(final Cam camOffset, final Scene scene) {
    double width = scene.getWidth();
    double height = scene.getHeight();
    camOffset.t.setX(width/2.0);
    camOffset.t.setY(height/2.0);
}

//=========================================================================
// setCamScale
//=========================================================================
public void setCamScale(final Cam cam, final Scene scene) {
    final Bounds bounds = cam.getBoundsInLocal();
    final double pivotX = bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth()/2;
    final double pivotY = bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()/2;
    final double pivotZ = bounds.getMinZ() + bounds.getDepth()/2;

    double width = scene.getWidth();
    double height = scene.getHeight();

    double scaleFactor = 1.0;
    double scaleFactorY = 1.0;
    double scaleFactorX = 1.0;
    if (bounds.getWidth() > 0.0001) {
        scaleFactorX = width / bounds.getWidth(); // / 2.0;
    }
    if (bounds.getHeight() > 0.0001) {
        scaleFactorY = height / bounds.getHeight(); //  / 1.5;
    }
    if (scaleFactorX > scaleFactorY) {
        scaleFactor = scaleFactorY;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = scaleFactorX;
    }
    cam.s.setX(scaleFactor);
    cam.s.setY(scaleFactor);
    cam.s.setZ(scaleFactor);
}

//=========================================================================
// setCamPivot
//=========================================================================
public void setCamPivot(final Cam cam) {
    final Bounds bounds = cam.getBoundsInLocal();
    final double pivotX = bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth()/2;
    final double pivotY = bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()/2;
    final double pivotZ = bounds.getMinZ() + bounds.getDepth()/2;

    //*1*
    cam.p.setX(pivotX);
    cam.p.setY(pivotY);
    cam.p.setZ(pivotZ);
    //*1*

    //*2*
    cam.ip.setX(-pivotX);
    cam.ip.setY(-pivotY);
    cam.ip.setZ(-pivotZ);
    //*2*
}

//=========================================================================
// setCamTranslate
//=========================================================================
public void setCamTranslate(final Cam cam) {
    final Bounds bounds = cam.getBoundsInLocal();
    final double pivotX = bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth()/2;
    final double pivotY = bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()/2;
    cam.t.setX(-pivotX);
    cam.t.setY(-pivotY);
}
```

So the method `setCamScale(...)` is understandable too, `setCamOffset(...)` is putting the root node (`camOffset`) in the centre of the screen, but i don´t understand the following 2 methods at all.

Of course, the child (`cam`) is not centered, by just putting the root node (`camOffset`) to the centre of the screen, but how do they center the xylophone / `cam` and set the pivot, using translations:

**Questions:**

**1.** Why are they using 3 different translations (`t`, `ip`, `p`)?

**2.** Referring to `setCamPivot(...)`: Why are they first translating `cam.p` to `pivotX`, `pivotY` and `pivotZ` and then `cam.ip` to `-pivotX`, `-pivotY` and `-pivotZ` (marked in the source code with *1* and *2*)? Should this not just put the group back to its position, where it has been positioned before, as if the whole method has never been called? This would be my guess, because I would expect, that an object is placed at the same position as before, if I first move it with the values X,Y,Z and then back with the same values -X,-Y,-Z in the opposite direction.

**3.** Same with the method `setCamTranslate(...)`: Why using another translation `cam.t`, moving the group (`cam`) with the same values `-pivotX`, `-pivotY` (and not `-pivotZ`), which they have used in the method `setCamPivot(...)`?

**Annotations:**

Of course, it works, the xylophone is in the centre of the screen and could be rotated perfectly, without a change in the point of rotation / pivot point, but I don´t understand how they did it.
I read everything about layoutBound, boundsInLocal, boundsInParent, blogs about layout and layout pass in javaFX https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/the_peculiarities_of_javafx_layout and http://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/javafx2-0-layout-a-class-tour/ and finally a lot of stackoverflow questions, but I still don´t understand the sense, behind the shown methods.

Before the call of `frameCam(...)`, they are calling:

```
double halfSceneWidth = 375;  // scene.getWidth()/2.0;
double halfSceneHeight = 275;  // scene.getHeight()/2.0;
cam.p.setX(halfSceneWidth);
cam.ip.setX(-halfSceneWidth);
cam.p.setY(halfSceneHeight);
cam.ip.setY(-halfSceneHeight);
```

I deleted this lines, because it does not change anything.

Comment: Question is cross-posted at https://community.oracle.com/thread/2622217 See answer there.